# Google SignInButton not appear

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, authentication, google-signin

I have a problem I can't do appear google SignInButton appear, but I have followed all the instructions to the letter! here's what I get :

[image]

and this is my code :

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

normally I should have this :

[image]

I hope you will be able to help me thank you in advance!

Comment: sometimes it will show at runtime, try to run your project into device

Comment: This is depends from parent layout. Add whole layout file.